# Font inheritance on input

Tags: css

Why does input get `Ubuntu` font instead of `monospace` font in this sample?

It is a tiny sample from some HTML code where the inputs are nested much deeper – but has the same effect.

Is there a general rule for what elements I have to specifically set `font-family` or inherit it? Input, label, button, …

Is it a bad idea to use something like this?

```
body * { font-family: xxx; }
```

What I want to do is set a "global font" and optionally set other font-families on elements where that is desired. Thought that was achieved by setting it on `html, body { }`. Obviously not.

---

#### Sample code:

```css
html, body {
  font-family: monospace;
}
.inp {
  font-family: monospace;
  /* or alternatively
  font-family: inherit; 
  */
}
```

```html
<p>Some text</p>
<input type="text" value="123456789.0" /><br />
<input type="text" value="123456789.0" class="inp" />
```

#### Result (picture):

The result looks like this in Fire Fox on Ubuntu:

> [image]

---

I'll add some pictures from Inspector in developer tools.

I was only looking at the *rules* section of the tools at first and as it say `monospace` I did not find the fault until I looked at *computed* ;)

[image: devtools]

From «Computed» on left and «Rules» on right:

- <body> has focus:

> [image: C:body]   [image: R:body]

- <p> has focus:

> [image: C:paragraph]  [image: R:paragraph]

- First <input> has focus:

> [image: C:input 1]       [image: R:paragraph]

- Second <input> has focus:

> [image: C:input 2]  [image: R:input 2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most HTML elements aren't assigned a `font-family` by the browser's user-agent style sheet, so they will inherit whatever you set on the `body` element.

Some elements, however, *do* receive styles from the user-agent, so they override the family you have on `body`. Inputs, buttons, and other form controls are often a problem.

In a CSS reset, it is very common to give these elements `font-family: inherit` example from [normalize.css](https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css/blob/master/normalize.css#L165):

```
input {
  font-family: inherit;
}
```

Inherit will set the input to use whatever font-family it would normally inherit, so it will then use your styles set on `body`.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it is inheriting the agent font from the `input` element.

The browser applies its own styling. In your case, the browser's styling on input takes precedence over inherited properties on html and body. On chrome you can see the user-agent style:

```
input {
    -webkit-writing-mode: horizontal-tb !important;
    text-rendering: auto;
    color: initial;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    word-spacing: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    text-indent: 0px;
    text-shadow: none;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: start;
    -webkit-appearance: textfield;
    background-color: white;
    -webkit-rtl-ordering: logical;
    cursor: text;
    margin: 0em;
    font: 400 13.3333px Arial;
    padding: 1px 0px;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-style: inset;
    border-color: initial;
    border-image: initial;
}
```

You'll be better off using `.inp` to style your element. Or for consistency you can style the input type:

```
input[type="text"] {
   font-family: monospace;
}
```